# GTK build missing include file gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf.h

Tags: gtk

I have installed  GTK, following the instructions here: http://www.gtk.org/download/win32_tutorial.php

Now I am trying to build a GTK hello world program from here: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk-tutorial/stable/c39.html#SEC-HELLOWORLD

I hit this error:

```
In file included from C:/gtk/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdkcairo.h:28:0,
                 from C:/gtk/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdk.h:33,
                 from C:/gtk/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h:30,
                 from gtk_hello_world.c:1:
C:/gtk/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdkpixbuf.h:34:35: fatal error: gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf
.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf.h>
                          ^
```

This seems to be the same problem as [How to repair "error: gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixdata.h: No such file or directory?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12075086/16582) but I do not understand the answer to that question.

Here is the command line to the compiler

```
C:\Users\James\code\smartone>gcc -o hello.exe gtk_hello_world.c -m32 -mms-bitfie
lds -IC:/gtk/include/gtk-3.0 -IC:/gtk/include/cairo -IC:/gtk/include/pango-1.0 -
IC:/tk/include/atk-1.0 -IC:/gtk/include/cairo -IC:/gtk/include/pixman-1 -IC:/gtk
/inlude -IC:/gtk/include/freetype2 -IC:/gtk/include -IC:/gtk/include/libpng15 -I
C:/gtk/include/libpng15 -IC:/gtk/include/glib-2.0 -IC:/gtk/lib/glib-2.0/include
-LC:/gtk/lib -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lgdi32 -limm32 -lshel32 -lole32 -Wl,-luuid -lpango
cairo-1.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lpangowin32-1.0 -lgdi32 -lpang
o-1.0 -lm -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdkpixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-
2.0 -lglib-2.0
```

This was mostly generated using

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0
-mms-bitfields -IC:/gtk/include/gtk-3.0 -IC:/gtk/include/cairo -IC:/gtk/include/
pango-1.0 -IC:/gtk/include/atk-1.0 -IC:/gtk/include/cairo -IC:/gtk/include/pixma
n-1 -IC:/gtk/include -IC:/gtk/include/freetype2 -IC:/gtk/include -IC:/gtk/includ
e/libpng15 -IC:/gtk/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -IC:/gtk/include/libpng15 -IC:/gtk/in
clude/glib-2.0 -IC:/gtk/lib/glib-2.0/include -LC:/gtk/lib -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lgdi3
2 -limm32 -lshell32 -lole32 -Wl,-luuid -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lfreetyp
e -lfontconfig -lpangowin32-1.0 -lgdi32 -lpango-1.0 -lm -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobjec
t -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is extremely old, but I ran into this error while compiling `xscreensaver` from source on Debian Stretch and found that the missing package was `libglade2-dev`, despite all intuition that might suggest it is `libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev`

Hope this might help the next guy looking for an answer to this one.

Answer (score 0):

We need the exact gcc command line that caused the error.  If the file is not found, it's because pkg-config couldn't pass to gcc the right location of your gdk-pixbuf installation.

First run `pkg-config --list-all | grep gdk-pixbuf` to get the exact name of the gdk-pixbuf module on you machine (for me it's `gdk-pixbuf-2.0`). The use that name, to check what directory pkg-config thinks gdk-pixbuf is installed:

`pkg-config --cflags gdk-pixbuf-2.0`

returns for me:

`-pthread -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libpng15 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include`

The `-I` tells here to gcc to include directory `/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0`. And this is where your file are not.

Comment: I am using pkg-config to generate the compiler flags.

Comment: I don't understand how you can get that result. There are duplicate items, some missing in the cflags (gdk-pixbuf), but present in the linker flags (the `-lgdkpixbuf-2.0`) which is a non-sense. Check your GTK installation, there is something certainly wrong there. BTW, be careful of arguments order in recent versions of gcc. The [GTK 3 documentation about how to build an application](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html) advises to use `gcc \`pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0\` -o example example.c \`pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0\`` to build.

Comment: Here is what `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` returns for me:
`-pthread
-D_REENTRANT
-I/usr/include/gtk-3.0
-I/usr/include/atk-1.0
-I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0
-I/usr/include/pango-1.0
-I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/
-I/usr/include/cairo
-I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0
-I/usr/include/glib-2.0
-I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include
-I/usr/include/harfbuzz
-I/usr/include/freetype2
-I/usr/include/pixman-1
-I/usr/include/directfb
-I/usr/include/libpng15
-I/usr/include/libdrm`